# Splitting a string with multiple delimiters in C++

Tags: c++, string, split, token, delimiter

SO I have to split the phrase: "Hello, everyone! This is: COSC-1436, SP18" into separate tokens, dismissing any punctuation minus the dash. So the output should be:

Hello

everyone

This

is

COSC-1436

SP18

And I then must encrypt each token, which I got covered. I'm just having trouble using multiple delimiters. Here's what I have currently.

Function prototype:
`void tokenize(const string&, const string&, vector<string>&);`

Function call:
`tokenize(code, " .,:;!?", tokens);`

Function definition:

```
void tokenize(const string& str, const string& delim, vector<string>& tokens)
{
    int tokenStart = 0;

    int delimPos = str.find_first_of(delim);

    while(delimPos != string::npos)
    {
        string tok = str.substr(tokenStart, delimPos - tokenStart);

        tokens.push_back(tok);

        delimPos++;

        tokenStart = delimPos;

        delimPos = str.find_first_of(delim, delimPos);

        if(delimPos == string::npos)
        {
            string tok = str.substr(tokenStart, delimPos - tokenStart);

            tokens.push_back(tok);
        }   
    }
}
```

The only problem is that there are now tokens as blank spaces where the program encountered the punctuation marks. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

After you found your delimiter you should move your substring start to the char which is `first_not_of` your delimiter. Basically change:

```
delimPos++;
```

to:

```
delimPos = str.find_first_not_of(delim, delimPos + 1);
```

This will ensure that when you have 2 or more delimiters in sequence, the `delimPos` is moved beyond the last one.

Alternatively you can try this:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello, everyone! This is: COSC-1436, SP18";
    std::string const delims{ " .,:;!?" };

    size_t beg, pos = 0;
    while ((beg = str.find_first_not_of(delims, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        pos = str.find_first_of(delims, beg + 1);
        std::cout << str.substr(beg, pos - beg) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/LJota9

```
Hello
everyone
This
is
COSC-1436
SP18
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help man! But I'm a bit of a coding newbie and I would like to implement what you said into the code I already have so I can understand it fully. What would I change in my code exactly to start my substring to the char which is first_not_of my delimiter?

Comment: @Tristan highlighted what you need to change to get it working in my answer

Comment: Dude thank you so much, you're a legend! It's all working now!

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `std::regex_iterator` since that's exactly what it was designed for.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "Hello, everyone! This is: COSC-1436, SP18";

    std::regex words_regex("[^\\s.,:;!?]+");
    auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), words_regex);
    auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i)
        std::cout << (*i).str() << '\n';
}
```

The output of that complete program will be this.

```
Hello
everyone
This
is
COSC-1436
SP18
```

Comment: That's pure C++11.

Comment: True, I somehow misread that you are using `std::regex` (not `std::basic_regex`).

Comment: Please not that regex is too much for this simple case and also ~30 times slower than Killzone Kid simple solution berlow (which is important for large files >10 MB)

Comment: "too much" is pretty subjective.  I'd love to see your actual measurement data from a 10 MB file, given the cost of a regex is in compiling it and they tend to operate much faster and more efficiently (O(log n)) than brute-force linear comparisons (O(n^2)).